# How do i remove all trailing space from word(both front and end white space) in comma seperated string

Tags: c#, regex, string

My string is like this:

```
Abc , xyz , pqr
```

**Final output**:

```
Abc,xyz,pqr
```

i want to remove all **trailing space**(from front and end) from **my word** whenever i encounter **comma** in my string but condittion is if my string contain comma or space.

Eg:

```
Abc pqr, ttt ooo
```

output:

```
Abc,pqr,ttt,ooo
```

(no space before or after the word)

Comment: Why is `Abc pqr, ttt ooo` -> `Abc,pqr,ttt,ooo`? There's no comma between `Abc` and `pqr` and between `ttt` and `ooo`.

Comment: Replace all the space with empty string.
Use replace method of string class as: Replace(" ","")

Comment: @TimSchmelter:oh sorry i forgot to mention that if space is encounter than replace that white apce with comma

Comment: if you just want to get rid of space, use Replace(' ','')

Comment: Downvoter please give me the reason for downvoting??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest and the best in perfomance:

```
    private static string SplitWordsByComma(string s)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(s.Trim(' ', ','), @"(?<=\b\w+\b)[\s,]+", ",");
    }
```

fastest (and properly working for bound cases):

```
    private static string SplitWordsByComma(string s)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            while (i < s.Length && !char.IsLetter(s[i]))
            {
                i++;
            }
            while (i < s.Length && char.IsLetter(s[i]))
            {
                sb.Append(s[i++]);
            }
            sb.Append(',');
        }
        return sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1).ToString();
    }
```

Comment: input:"   Abc , xyz ,    pqr   "   output:   Abc,xyz,pqr,

Comment: Also, i have my doubts about "best in performance" with regex.

Comment: @TimSchmelter it's much better than split and concatenate strings agait

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky: but i have not claimed that it's the best in performance. A `StringBuilder` approach would be much more efficient when the string is large, otherwise it doesn't matter and i'd use the most readable approach.

Comment: @TimSchmelter best in pefrormance from alternatives purposed above and below. But I added an SB solution for those who want it.

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky:cant we do this without using any loops?

Comment: @mariapithia well, regex works fine for the most part of possible string. And surely you cannot do it without loops, but in `TimSchmelter`'s code they are hidden in `Split` and `Join` methods. So, two loops instead of one and extra memory allocations, but only two lines of code. Choose needed code yourself.

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky: fyi, the regex approach requires `11.68` seconds, the `String.Split`+`String.Join` takes only `1.28` second with a 60000-length string and 1000 repetitions.

Comment: @TimSchmelter hmm, okay. I've got same results. Very strange, I know that regex is much slower than simple string iteration, but I didn't suggest that it will be 10 times slower than not only one single iteration, but two iterations with multiple memory prealloc. I agree that your variant is better than my regex.

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky: the `StringBuilder` approaches are still less efficient than `String.Split+Join`, so  a `60000`-char-string is not large enough. Also, a little nitpicking, `char.IsLetter` is not only including `" "` and `","`. You are removing for example all numbers.

Comment: @TimSchmelter StringBuilder cannot be slower :) It seems to `char.IsLetter` is evil-doer. And I know that i remove all non-alpha chars, I think it's an expected behaviour

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky: of course it can, my own StringBuilder approach also needs 3 seconds. It is a combination of StringBuilder and pure string methods like `Substring` and `IndexOfAny` which should be most efficient. `String.Join` is so efficient when you use the overload with a `String[]`.

Answer (score 5):

So all spaces and commas are separators and you want to remove all consecutive duplicates. You can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) with [`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string[] parts = input.Split(new []{' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string result = string.Join(",", parts);
```

This is my favourite since it's readable, maintainable and efficient. I've tested it against a regex approach  with a 60000-length string and 1000 repetitions:

```
Regex:  11.68 seconds
String.Split + String.Join: 1.28 seconds
```

But if the string is very large you might want to use a `StringBuilder` approach.

This is the best result so far:

```
public static string SplitAnyKeepSingleSeparator(string input, string separator, params char[] delimiter)
{
    if(input == null) return null;
    input = input.Trim(delimiter);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
    int index = 0;
    int delimiterIndex = input.IndexOfAny(delimiter);
    while (delimiterIndex != -1)
    {
        string token = input.Substring(index, delimiterIndex - index);
        sb.Append(token).Append(separator);
        index = delimiterIndex + 1;
        while (delimiter.Contains(input[index])) index++;
        delimiterIndex = input.IndexOfAny(delimiter, index);
    }
    sb.Append(input.Substring(index));
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

But with a 60,000 character-string it's still less efficient than the `String.Split`+`Join` approach.

Comment: consider this input:plumber, plumber  output:plumber,,plumber

Comment: @mariapithia: have a look again.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :)

```
string inputStr = "ABC, cde , fgh, IJk";
string outputStr = inputStr.Replace(' ', '');
```

OR

```
string outputStr = string.Join(",",(inputStr.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Comment: if _ABC DEF , GHJ , KLM_ your answer will  remove the space between _ABC DEF_

Comment: oh.. I didnt saw the second example.. just Final Output.. ohh. well..  So the solution is: string outputStr = string.Join(",",(inputStr.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

Comment: please consider both the cases

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
string input = "input:plumber, plumber output:plumber,,plumber";
input = input.Replace(" ", ",").Trim();
while (input.Contains(",,")) 
{
    input = input.Replace(",,", ",");
}
```

Edited...

I have tested the answers provided and compared with mine. (in VB.net)

```
Dim input As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\SARVESH\Desktop\abc.txt")
Dim stp As New Diagnostics.Stopwatch
stp.Start()
input = input.Replace(" ", ",").Trim()
While input.Contains(",,")
    input = input.Replace(",,", ",")
End While
stp.Stop()
MessageBox.Show(stp.ElapsedMilliseconds)

input = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\SARVESH\Desktop\abc.txt")
stp.Reset()
stp.Restart()
input = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input.Trim(" "c, ","c), "(?<=\b\w+\b)[\s,]+", ",")
stp.Stop()
MessageBox.Show(stp.ElapsedMilliseconds)

input = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\SARVESH\Desktop\abc.txt")
stp.Reset()
stp.Restart()
Dim parts As String() = input.Split({" "c, ","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim result As String = String.Join(",", parts)
stp.Stop()
MessageBox.Show(stp.ElapsedMilliseconds)
```

Tested on a string of 10616532 characters.

Tim Schmelter' code works much faster... does the task in 141 ms.

Mine does the same in 512 ms.

regex does the same in 1221 ms.

Comment: sorry dont want to use any loop

Comment: @mariapithia I have tested this code on a string of 10616532 characters and it does this in just 500 ms.

Comment: @TimSchmelter split and join seems to be fastest.